# ESP8266 WIFI_AP_STA mode

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm working with the ESP8266. And I got caught in a spot. I'll be happy if you can help me.

The project I want to do is, the ESP8266 will connect to the modem and after it is connected, it will start broadcasting itself as an access point. From my computer I also want to connect to the ESP8266 and send the modifier data.

When I plug in the ESP8266 in `WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); /*1*/` code, there is no connection with the ESP modem. And so I can not send data from the computer to the modifier.

When I run the ESP8266 in `//WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); /*2*/` code, it makes a connection to my machine. I can connect to the ESP from my computer but it does not send data. After a while, the connection to my modem is disconnected.

Here is what I want to ask shortly. How can I run the ESP8266 regularly in AP and STA modes?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char* ssid = "Stationssid";   //agin ssid
const char* password = "1234567890";//agin password
const char* host="192.168.4.1";   // hosted host
const char* apssid = "APssid";    // I will broadcast the ssid name of the network
const char* appassword = "1234567890"; // I will broadcast the encryption of the network
String cgv; // my variable to read the data from the client
int k;
const int port=5001; // port i am connected to
WiFiServer server(80); // AP server description
WiFiClient clientSTA; // client mod for station mod
WiFiClient clientAP; // Client name for AP mode

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); /*1*/ //ESP8266 works in both AP mode and station mode
  //WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); /*2*/  // ESP8266 works in station mode
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); // given the network

  Serial.print(ssid);
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    // not connected to the network
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(ssid);
  Serial.println(" Connected to WiFi address.");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());     // Printing IP address
  Serial.print("Signal Power: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.RSSI());        // printing signal strength
  clientSTA.connect(host,port);
  Serial.println("setup settings made.");
}

void loop() {
  if(!clientSTA.connect(host,port)) {
    // If there is no connect from host and port given
    Serial.println("No Station connection");
    k=0;
    return;
  }
  while(clientSTA.connected()) // while in station mode
  {
    if(k==0)
    { 
      Serial.println("Station connection available");
     // WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);  /*setup for wifi mode 2 * / / If WiFi is in modem station mode, then it will work in both modes after connect
      WiFi.softAP(apssid, appassword); // Start AP mode
      IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP(); // IP address for AP mode
      Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
      Serial.println(myIP);
      clientAP=server.available(); // Replace client mode of AP mode with server
      server.begin(); // server  start
      k=1;
    }
    while(clientSTA.available()) {
      // If data is coming from the station
      Serial.println("Data is coming from the station");
      cgv=clientSTA.readStringUntil('\r'); // read incoming data
      Serial.print("Data: ");
      Serial.println(cgv);
      clientSTA.flush();  // clear clientSTA
      cgv="";
      if(clientAP) {
        // If clientAP is active
        Serial.println("There is an AP link"); 
        clientAP.print(cgv); // send incoming data to clientAP
      }
    }
    if(clientAP.connected()) {
      // If clientAP is connected
      while(clientAP.available()) {
        // If the clientAP da data is coming
        Serial.println("Data comes from access point");
        cgv=clientAP.readStringUntil('\r'); // read incoming data
        Serial.print("AP data: ");
        Serial.println(cgv);
        clientAP.flush(); // clear clientAP
        clientSTA.print(cgv); // send incoming data to station
        cgv="";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was facing the same problem, but the problem with this approach is that it switches the channel for every sta connection. either every time we have to get the channel of the AP and connect accoarding to that channel. But the better approach is using painlessMesh Library. We can create a mesh network with it and can receive or broadcast through different nodes without taking care of WiFi modes and fuctioning.
I doing the same work. you can have a look in my [github account](https://github.com/vbshightime?tab=repositories)

Answer (score 0):

This because when you softAP channel is in 1 and when you AP+station channel moves to 9. so the tcp connection is reset. Your problem is already discussed here [LINK](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/119#issuecomment-157418957)

Answer (score 0):

set `WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);` , leave and `if(WiFi.status() !=WL_CONNECTED)` with the Void Loop. the STA normally don't present problems creating the station, but on some versions of the WiFi.h lib, there is no reconnect working feature, try this out and see if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am glad if i can help.
Down is a snipped of a working ap_sta solution.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
const char* ssid = "wifi";
const char* password = "radoslavov";
const char *apssid = "ESP32";
const char *appassword = "radorado";
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(1000);
Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
}
Serial.println("Connected to WiFi network");
Serial.print("IP address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


if (!WiFi.softAP(apssid, appassword)) 
{
log_e("Soft AP creation failed.");
while(1);
}
IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
Serial.println(myIP);
server.begin();

Serial.println("Server started");

}

void loop() {
Serial.println("chaka");
// Your code here
WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming 
//clients
Serial.println(client.localIP());
if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
Serial.println("New Client.");           // print a message out the 
//serial port
String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold 
//incoming data from the client
while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's 
//connected
if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read 
//from the client,
char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial 
//monitor
if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline 
//character

// if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a 
//row.
// that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
// HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 
//OK)
// and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a 
//blank line:
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-type:text/html");
client.println();

// the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
client.print("Click <a href=\"/H\">here</a> to turn ON the LED. 
<br>");
client.print("Click <a href=\"/L\">here</a> to turn OFF the LED. 
<br>");

// The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
client.println();
// break out of the while loop:
break;
} else {    // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
currentLine = "";
}
} else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage 
return character,
currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
}

// Check to see if the client request was "GET /H" or "GET /L":
if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /H")) {
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);               // GET /H turns the 
//LED on
}
if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /L")) {
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);                // GET /L turns the 
LED off
}
}
}
// close the connection:
client.stop();
Serial.println("Client Disconnected.");
}
}
```